# Definition of "Google-owned services" for Firebase Cloud Functions within the Spark plan

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Firebase Cloud Functions within the free tier (Spark plan) of Firebase can't make any outbound requests unless they're to 'Google-owned services':

> The Spark plan allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services.[1]

This is pretty clear and makes sense, allowing random outbound traffic within the free plan would surely be vulnerable to misuse. However, I'm struggling to find what is and isn't in the scope of "Google-owned services". Is this only restricted to the Firebase API and Google APIs?

Asking this because *.firebase.com for instance is blocked.

[1] https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: There is no documented list of URLs that is accessible or not. But if you think a URL is wrongfully blocked under the spark plan, report it here or [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. In this case though: there is no useful web API running on `*.firebase.com`, it's just the legacy Firebase web site. Are you sure that's the URL you are trying to access?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ok, thats a shame. Can understand its difficult to compile such a comprehensive list. Will report the URL's that are blocked!
PS: there ARE a couple of things still running on that domain :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after contacting Firebase support, they kindly pointed me to an overview of which Google Services are supported by Cloud Functions. While this isn't an overview of whitelisted URL's, it certainly helps getting a better picture. The overview [1]:

> - Cloud Storage
> - Cloud Bigtable
> - Cloud Spanner
> - Cloud Datastore
> - Cloud Machine Learning Platform
> - Cloud Natural Language API
> - Cloud Speech API
> - Cloud Translation API
> - Cloud Vision API
> - Cloud BigQuery
> - Cloud Pub/Sub
> - Stackdriver Logging
> - Firebase (DB, Storage, Analytics, Auth)

This explains why the API I was trying to reach isn't working; it isn't listed in the overview.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/services