# Is it possible to use google-spreadsheet-to-json and deploy as a firebase function?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm having trouble in getting the data via http client using firebase function. The error that i get always after deployment is :

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND spreadsheets.google.com spreadsheets.google.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
```

I don't know what's the cause of this. Is it the my account in firebase is free? or i need to upgrade my account to access any spreadsheets?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access outside network on a free plan; what is inside and what's outside is of course up to google (it says "Google services only" in the documentation). That question has been answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43682157/definition-of-google-owned-services-for-firebase-cloud-functions-within-the-sp). According to that answer, you should not expect access to Spreadsheets API from free tier.

Latest list of supported services:

> Cloud BigQuery
>
> Cloud Bigtable
>
> Cloud Data Loss Prevention
>
> Cloud Datastore
>
> Cloud DNS
>
> Cloud Firestore
>
> Cloud Machine Learning Engine
>
> Cloud Natural Language API
>
> Cloud Pub/Sub
>
> Cloud Resource Manager
>
> Cloud Spanner
>
> Cloud Speech-to-Text API
>
> Cloud SQL
>
> Cloud Storage
>
> Cloud Translation API
>
> Cloud Vision API
>
> Cloud Video Intelligence API
>
> Firebase (DB, Storage, Analytics, Auth)
>
> Google Stackdriver Debugger
>
> Google Stackdriver Error Reporting
>
> Google Stackdriver Logging
>
> Google Stackdriver Monitoring
>
> Google Stackdriver Trace
>
> Google Compute Engine

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!